# Issue with Chrome and Select boxes and option size

Tags: jquery, html, google-chrome

I've noticed an issue recently with Chrome and Select boxes.  The size of the options has got much larger and there appears to be extra padding.  I know we can't style select option, so wondered if anyone else had this issue and had a solution.

[image]

Even happens on JQ UI datepicker control.

[image]

It's not an issue on IE though.

I've created a new page with no style sheets, no jquery and just one simple select box with 3 options.

This is the output from Chrome and IE.

[image]

I'm on Windows 10 if that helps.

[image]

Comment: Use <ul> <li> instead of <select> if you want same style in all browsers

Comment: This is not a general Chrome issue, Chrome isn't doing this.  I'm guessing your code is within `<pre>` tags, and that's causing some of your issues...

Comment: You cannot style select boxes isnt a correct statement, You can style them by putting them inside a container and then giving a style to that container.

Comment: Can you provide a live example of this?

Comment: My code is not with <pre> tags.

Comment: I didn't say style the select, I said style the select OPTION.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps:

```css
select {
        width:400px; /*width of text box*/
        height:40px; /*height of text box*/
        color:red; /*color of text inside the text box*/
        background:yellow; /*background color of text box*/
    }
```

```html
<select>
    <option>Maths</option>
    <option>Physics</option>
    <option>Chemistry</option>
    </select>
```